# mysql concat columns passed as strings

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, concatenation

I would need to concatenate column values where the column names are passed as strings. I have a client who has a poorly designed MySql table which looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
| id | column_index | c1 | c2 | c3 | .... |c50|
```

the column_index field is a comma separated string of column names like c1,c5,c11 and what I'd like to do is to write a single select query (without a stored procedure or so) to return only concatenated column values according to which columns have been defined as the index.

Something like this:

```
SELECT id, column_index, CONCAT_WS(',' FOR col_name IN column_index)
```

Is it any way to create a query doing something similar to it for MySql?

Answer (score 0):

Something is seriously wrong with your data structure.  Perhaps you should put your efforts into fixing that rather than creating overly complicated queries.

That said, the following is not pretty, but should work:

```
select id, column_index,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when find_in_set('c1', column_index) > 0 then c1 end),
                 (case when find_in_set('c2', column_index) > 0 then c2 end),
                 (case when find_in_set('c3', column_index) > 0 then c3 end),
                 . . .
                ) as vals
. . .
```

Comment: Are you missing a `@colnames = column_index,` after `id,`

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . I just didn't interpret `column_index` as a column name.  Curious data structure.

Comment: I agree this structure is seriously wrong. However this is my client's production database and I have only read access there so I cannot modify it. That's why I need to play with a comlicated sql then.